# IE closes connection on file download before end of download

Tags: internet-explorer, apache2, download

IE randomly closes the connection whenever we try to download a file from our server (mp3 file).

It sometimes downloads the whole file, but it sometimes just doesn't download at all.

I've added %X to the apache logs, and whenever the download fails, instead of "+" I get an "x" in the log.

Does anyone have any idea why this would happen?

Comment: Does this only happen with IE?
Does it only happen with large files?
Does it only happen with mp3 files?

Comment: I have the same problem. It seems to happen the first time I download the file, but not other times. The problem is prevalent in IE, but has been reported in Chrome too.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  My page has a button that opens the URL in a new window.  The content-type header is text/cvs and the Content-disposition header is "attachment".  Sometimes the window remains open until the download dialog opens, but most of the time it just closes after the server responds.